# Перекрыть border внешнего div-а элементами li

Tags: css

У нас есть меню `ul li` где каждый `li` имеет свой `background-color`, все `ul` в обертке `div` у которого свой `border`. 
Подскажите какой наилучший способ перекрыть `border` основного блока `div` меню, таким образом чтобы каждый `li` "убирал, перекрывал, был поверх" этого `border`. т.е. чтобы не было видно внешнего `border` под каждым элементом `li`. 
В примере ниже вы уведите что `ul` в блоке `.menu` поэтому красный `border` всегда ниже `li`, хотелось ,не уменьшая высоту блока `.menu` убрать красный `border` под `li`

http://jsfiddle.net/zk2djyqf/2/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так? http://jsfiddle.net/zk2djyqf/5/

```
ul {
  /* ... */
  margin-bottom: -1px;    
}
```

---

Или так? http://jsfiddle.net/zk2djyqf/6/

```
ul li {
  /* ... */
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4778c3;
}

<ul>
  <li>
    <a>item1</a>
  </li><li>
    <a>item2</a>
  </li><li>
    <a>item3</a>
  </li><li>
    <a>item4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Отличное решение с минимальными телодвижениями. При этом отрицательный `margin` должен нормально отобразиться во всех браузерах. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, вместо border использовать `box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0 0 #F00;`

Другой вариант - использовать 1-пиксельный gif в качестве background-image растянув его c repeat-x по низу

Еще вариант - если известна высота блока (и она фиксирована) - можно попробовать поинрать с position:absolue, сделав контейнер div на 1px меньше высоты ul, у которой, в свою очередь, `position:absolue`

Пока все, что приходит на ум

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, пока остановился на `margin` но идея с `box-shadow` тоже очень понравилась !

Answer (score 0):

Если никто ничего умнее не посоветует, то:

Уберите `border` у дива и добавьте `background: url('img.jpg') left bottom repeat-x`

Где картинка это точечка высотой в требуемую вам высоту бордера.

Получится псевдо бордер, перекрываемый кнопками.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, так тоже можно но проще `margin`.